# word choice: someone who sticks with their group

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to find a word to fit in this context:

you are a sitting _____

I want the word to show they are a follower in a teenage girl group. Like one with a head girl and the person I'm describing being a follower.
I'm trying to write a song. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your context sentence, as the only thing that comes to mind is, "You are a sitting duck" -- not what you're looking for. How someone would be a *sitting follower* is beyond me.

Comment: Especially in school cliques, I've heard these referred to as "satellites"

Comment: I've heard them referred to as "betas" (as opposed to a "alpha-males" or "alpha-females")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to work "sitting" in there, but the phrase "**second fiddle**" may provide a similar sound.  "Second fiddle" is defined by Merriam-Webster as "one that plays a supporting or subservient role".

The phrase comes from the world of music, in which the most accomplished and/or skillful musician for a particular instrument (violin, in this case) is assigned "first chair" in that section, and the less accomplished musicians are referred to as the second/third/fourth/etc. chairs.

A somewhat sillier variant is "second banana".

Comment: Another somewhat similar-sounding term might be "running dog", which is defined by Merriam-Webster as "one who blindly follows someone else's orders".  This is apparently translated from a Cold-War-era Chinese term, and is somewhat harsher in its connotation.  (Unsolicited advice: Don't write checks you can't cash.)

Answer (score 0):

Acolyte may work, given the context.

Comment: This is a good word that may work (as you've said) given the context. However, you should include sources and a definition. If you do that, you'll be more likely to get votes.